# What does '%,' and '.-1,%' and ',%' or '%,' mean in SQL/Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, powerschool

the code specifically I am referring to is:

```
AND (
(','||to_char('~[gpv:lt]')||',' LIKE '%,' || to_char(log.logtypeid) || '.' || 
    CASE WHEN log.subtype is null 
    THEN ' ' 
    ELSE log.subtype 
    END || ',%')
OR (','||to_char('~[gpv:lt]')||',' LIKE '%,' || to_char(log.logtypeid) || '.-1,%')
OR (to_char(log.logtypeid) LIKE 
    CASE 
    WHEN to_char('~[gpv:lt]') = '-1' 
    THEN '%' 
    ELSE ','||to_char('~[gpv:lt]')||',' 
    END)  
)
```

Any clarification would be great. Thank you!

Comment: `%` is the SQL wildcard, similar to a `*` for the `dir` or `ls` command.

Comment: Downvoted, no effort shown.  Googled 'percent sign in sql'....

Comment: I wish I could downvote you for not being able to comprehend the english language. I am aware of % being a wild card. What I am not aware of is the use of comma's, period's, and when they are used with %

Comment: For those not aware: the `~[gpv:lt]` stuff is from the PowerSchool tag language. It interpolates the value of `lt` parameter from the URL or POST data. This is the first powerschool question I've seen on stackexchange... I added a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this expression:

```
(','||to_char('~[gpv:lt]')||',' LIKE '%,' || to_char(log.logtypeid) || '.' || 
    CASE WHEN log.subtype is null 
    THEN ' ' 
    ELSE log.subtype 
    END || ',%')
```

It is an example of this idiom:

```
','||a||',' LIKE '%,'||b||',%'
```

in which `a` is your `lt` parameter, and `b` a "type dot subtype" string. This comparison can be used whenever you have an `a` string that is a comma-separated list of values, and a `b` string that is a single value, and you want to know whether the list `a` contains the value `b`.

To see why it's written that way, first look at this attempt to do it more simply:

```
a LIKE '%'||b||'%'
```

We take `b`, put a wildcard at the front and back, and match `a`. This will be true if `a` is for example `1,2,3` and `b` is `2`. It will also unfortunately be true if `a` is `12,34,56` and `b` is `2`. `LIKE` doesn't do comma-separated list parsing, just string matching.

So next you might try this:

```
a LIKE '%,'||b||',%'
```

Now if `b` is `2`, the pattern is `%,2,%` - which will match any string containing `,2,` so it is true for `a`=`1,2,3` and false for `a`=`12,34,56`. Unfortunately it's also false for `a`=`2,3,4` because the 2 doesn't have a comma before it and false for `a`=`0,1,2` because the 2 doesn't have a comma after it.

For the next improvement there are 2 ways to go. You can use separate pattern cases to match `b` at the beginning, middle, and end of `a` (if you go this way, using a regular expression will help make it readable!)

The other way is to modify `a` to match the existing pattern. We didn't match `0,1,2` or `2,3,4` because the first element of the list and the last element of the list aren't surrounded by commas. But if we add a comma to the beginning of `a` before matching, then the first element of the list *will* be surrounded by commas! And add another comma to the end of `a` to make sure the last element is also surrounded by commas.

```
','||a||',' LIKE '%,'||b||',%'
```

Now when `a` is `0,1,2` and `b` is `2`, the `LIKE` expression becomes:

```
',0,1,2,' LIKE '%,2,%'
```

which is a match! The first wildcard absorbs the `,0,1` and the `,2,` is found. The last wildcard matches a zero-length substring at the end, which is allowed.

Comment: Good explanation as well. The only thing that still doesn't make sense is that the `a` in your example is a (complicated/obfuscated) constant: `to_char('~[gpv:lt]')` and is not derived from a column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as I mentioned in my comment on the question, that `~[gpv:lt]` stuff is a powerschool tag. It will expand the value of the `lt` parameter that was sent in the HTTP POST or GET. What you're seeing here is basically equivalent to a fragment of a PHP page containing an SQL query with `$_POST["lt"]` in it. Except that the powerschool tag language is infinitely more horrible than PHP. (Note: I'm not a PHP fan!)

Comment: So you are saying that you expect the SQL query that we see to be pre-processed, and that the SQL in the question isn't the _real_ SQL that is being sent to the database because that `~[gpv:lt]` is replaced _before_ the SQL is executed?

Comment: Yes, the poster of this question could have made it clearer by mentioning more of the context... looking at his previous questions (which apparently relate to the same query) this is an ongoing problem. He doesn't seem to know where the "powerschool stuff" ends and the "oracle stuff" begins. But I was trying to just ignore that in my answer and focus on the reason for all the percents and commas

Comment: Yeah, it is a little confusing considering ~[gpv:lt] is within the ~[tlist_sql; , and I assumed everything within was part of the oracle query. I haven't formerly learned SQL/Oracle or HTML/CSS/Javascript, so my lack of fully understanding would be the reasoning behind the lack of context, so I do apoligize. I appreciate you both taking the time and explaining it. I will try and dissect everything you both wrote.

Comment: @AdamKrause start with this: everything that starts with a tilde is a powerschool tag. People who know oracle but not powerschool will be confused by those. All the powerschool tags inside the tlist_sql are replaced, then the query (which starts after `~[tlist_sql;` and ends at the next `;` or the matching `]`) is sent to the Oracle server. The result that comes back from the Oracle server is printed using the template between the `]` and the `[/tlist_sql]`

Answer (score 1):

`%` is known as a [`Wildcard character`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character). More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Those `-1,%` are string literals and are used to build a `LIKE` condition based on several contants and the values of some columns. The statement shows a basic misunderstanding on how to use string literals in Oracle.

Take for example this condition:

```
','||to_char('~[gpv:lt]')||',' LIKE '%,' || to_char(log.logtypeid) || '.-1,%'
```

The `to_char('~[gpv:lt]')` is totally useless because it simply converts the string constant `'~[gpv:lt]'` to ... a string. So that part could be simplified to:

```
',~[gpv:lt],' LIKE '%,' || to_char(log.logtypeid) || '.-1,%'
```

which essentially says:

Compare the string constant `',~[gpv:lt],'` with the result of the concatenation of the following

1. the constant `'%,'`
2. the value of the column `log.logtypeid` converted to a `varchar`
3. the constant `'.-1,%'`

So, assuming `log.logtypeid` contains the value `42` this generates the condition

```
',~[gpv:lt],' LIKE '%,42.-1,%'
```

This could only match if the column `log.logtypeid` contained a value like `~[gpv:lt]`. Which would be a bit confusing as columns named "id" usually don't contain "structured data" like that.

If I had to guess, I'd say the data model is *heavily* de-normalized and those columns store comma separated, structured data (maybe even structured key/value pairs).

The other conditions do something similar.

Comment: beat me by 5 minutes... posted mine anyway